# How to trigger selenium tests from Jira

Tags: c#, selenium, jenkins, jira

I have a requirement in which I have to trigger selenium tests from Jira. Selenium tests are written in `C#`.
The complete work flow should be like:

- Start test execution from Jira using any 3rd party plugin.
- The test will be running in aws using jenkins build pipeline.
- After the test is completed the results should be updated in Jira

I had read about Xray plugin for Jira but there the build has to be triggered from jenkins which i don't need as i want the test execution to be triggered from Jira.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a CI server in between your test execution environment and JIRA. Otherwise there will be no configuration control over your test jobs. JIRA is for project management and monitoring. *At present , It cannot be used for controlling slave nodes and executable targets*.

The technical side of things is still managed on a CI server. If you don't want to have a static hosted Jenkins server , you can go with following two options.

1. **[CircleCI](https://circleci.com/)**
2. **[JenkinsX](https://jenkins.io/projects/jenkins-x/)** in kubernetes.

Also you are using **AWS**.

You can spin up ec2 instance and configure your selenium job to run on that specific instance . 
If you like complexity and dynamic coding , then you can also use AWS Lambda. [This blog](https://medium.com/@Moatazeldebsy/ui-testing-using-selenium-webdriver-and-chrome-inside-aws-lambda-77a17ec64862) can give some inspiration to begin with. JIRA has [apps](https://zapier.com/app-directory/aws-lambda/integrations/jira) to directly connect with AWS lambda.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could provide more info on running tests in aws using jenkins or lambda when an action occurs in jira.

Comment: https://blackboard.github.io/lambda-selenium/ , can provide you the tutorial for setting up nodes using AWS lambda. All you have to do is call this lambda function from JIRA. As an admin, you must have zapier installed so that you can call AWS lambda functions.

Comment: I could only find examples for java and Node.js. it would be really helpful if you could provide examples for selenium scripts written in c#